# Google Maps : How to open an InfoWindow by hovering a link?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have on my page a map on the left with about 40 points and the list of these 40 points on the right.
So you know, when you click on a point on the map, the "info window" is displayed where you can see some information about it.
I can't find how I can simply open the "info window" on the map by making a "hover" on the corresponding link, and consequently close all the other info windows.

Does anybody have an idea about this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All you have to is simply bind mouseover event into your marker and then info balloon will appear.

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
      marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
});
```

There is an example page here 
Also know that for better explanation of how map coding works on google always check the documentation first.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/

Hope this helps
Myra

Comment: Hi Myra,

thanks for this snippet.
After searching on google and the AIP documentation, i've find this fonction "openInfoWindowHtml", but don't understand how to use it :/

So, instead of "html" i have to put the html code contained in the info window?

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 12):

Found this doing a Google Search. This code below works for Google Maps API v3.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

v2 was out at the time of the question being asked so if anyone else stumbles across this post, my example is compatible with v3.

Answer (score 2):

You Mmay try `addListener` with `mouseover`

```
marker.addListener('mouseover', function () {
        infowindow.open(mapObj, marker);
    });
```